# Junit5 test containers with custom Spring annotation?

Tags: spring-boot, junit, annotations, integration-testing, testcontainers

I have an idea that I'm not sure if it's feasible. I have multiple microservices that I'm trying to write integration tests for (in Junit5), most of them only need one test container (usually a database) but some might also need multiple (i.e. database + kafka). Is it possible to write a custom annotation to initialize the containers I need? The idea is having an annotation such as @NeedContainers("database", "kafka") and it will initialize the containers specified before the tests are run. I've looked around and tried using AspectJ to trigger something, but my custom annotation doesn't seem to trigger at all (sans actual container). This is the structure that I have so far:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
public @interface TestContainer {
   
   public String value() default "";
}
```

```
@Aspect
public class ContainerInitializer {
   private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ContainerInitializer.class);
   

   @Before("@annotation(TestContainer)")
   public void initContainer() {
      logger.info("CONTAINER INITIALIZED");
   }

}
```

and ideally a test container can be initialized within the `ContainerInitializer` class when the test is annotated like so

```
@FunctionalSpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@TestContainer("database")
class IntegrationTest{
 //tests here
}
```

is it even possible to do this with a custom annotation? Or should I just stick with `@Container` or extending an abstract class (which is what I have right now)? Is there a smarter approach to this?

Comment: Isn't that more of a solution looking for a problem? Create 1 or 2 base test classes that start the needed containers, or just start all the containers always and re-use them. AspectJ solution won't help here as the containers are needed while starting the application, so you need to hook into the cycle really early on.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for the input, you might be right. This idea is definitely a bit convoluted. I'm not very versed in AspectJ so I wasn't sure how early into the cycle it can jump into. I guess not early enough?

Comment: I agree with @M.Deinum here. Also, you can always call methods in `@Before` and `@BeforeAll` methods and add abstractions through this mechanism, rather than using AspectJ, which sounds overly complex for this use case. You also don't need to use `@Testcontianers` annotation, consider calling `start()` for more control on the lifecycle.